# Config AttributeError

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

i am using google colab to create AI art with vqgan+clip and i am getting this error

```
ConfigAttributeError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
        <ipython-input-8-1f51aa4d37d6> in <module>()
             17 print('Using seed:', seed)
             18 
        ---> 19 model = load_vqgan_model(args.vqgan_config, args.vqgan_checkpoint).to(device)
 

20 perceptor = clip.load(args.clip_model, jit=False)[0].eval().requires_grad_(False).to(device)
     21 # clock=deepcopy(perceptor.visual.positional_embedding.data)
```

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/omegaconf/dictconfig.py in _get_node(self, key, validate_access, throw_on_missing_value, throw_on_missing_key)
468         if value is None:
469             if throw_on_missing_key:
--> 470                 raise ConfigKeyError(f"Missing key {key}")
471         elif throw_on_missing_value and value._is_missing():
472             raise MissingMandatoryValue("Missing mandatory value: $KEY")

ConfigAttributeError: Missing key model
full_key: model
object_type=dict